# what propreties does a diagram item have to be able to make defference of it's two different copies?

Tags: c#, devexpress, shapes

i want to attach to every shape dragged into `DiagramControl` some code such as previous and next but i don't know how to do it...
if i have the same shape and dragged it twice into the diagram control does shape1 and shape2 have different id? I mean how can I tell the difference between item1 and item2 because i want to add some attributes to each one and how could I access each one to edit?
I've tried to create a class and extend it from diagram item but it didn't solve my problem

Comment: I've not used the DiagramControl extensively but when I did I made use of the DiagramDataBindingBehavior.  This defines a template for each shape and allows you to bind a list of objects to your view model.  It is created by clicking the arrow in the designer and then DiagramDataBindingBehavior and then "Run Template Designer".  Also the help is good and if you're really stuck send them a support query, they get back pretty quickly

Comment: Thank you Tim , I'll try the DiagramDataBindingBehavior ,am not allowed to send them a support query because am using the trial

Answer (score 0):

@Ghaith: You still qualify for support if you are within your 30 day trial period. Per the [support services information page](https://documentation.devexpress.com/GeneralInformation/2219/Support-Services):

> If you are evaluating our products on a trial basis, you have access
>   to 30 days of free support during your evaluation period.

If you want to be able to identify one instance of a shape from another instance of that same shape, you could handle the DiagramControl's [AddingNewItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraDiagram.DiagramControl.AddingNewItem.event) and assign a unique identifier to the shape via its Tag property. For instance:

```
private void diagramControl1_AddingNewItem(object sender, DevExpress.XtraDiagram.DiagramAddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
     e.Item.Tag = new Guid();
}
```